# Given 4 objects, how to figure out whether exactly 2 have a certain property

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I have another question on how to make most elegant solution to this problem, since I cannot afford to go to computer school right so my actual "pure programming" CS knowledge is not perfect or great. This is basically an algorhythm problem (someone please correct me if I am using that wrong, since I don't want to keep saying them and embarass myself)

I have 4 objects. Each of them has an species property that can either be a dog, cat, pig or monkey. So a sample situation could be:

object1.species=pig
object2.species=cat
object3.species=pig
object4.species=dog

Now, if I want to figure out if all 4 are the same species, I know I could just say:

```
if  ( (object1.species==object2.species) 
    && (object2.species==object3.species)
    && (object3.species==object4.species)
) {
    // They are all the same animal (don't care WHICH animal they are)
}
```

But that isn't so elegant right? And if I suddenly want to know if EXACTLY 3 or 2 of them are the same species (don't care WHICH species it is though), suddenly I'm in spaghetti code.

I am using Objective C although I don't know if that matters really, since the most elegant solution to this is I assume the same in all languages conceptually? Anyone got good idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely what sets and counted sets are for.

```
BOOL allSameSpecies(NSArray *animals) {
    NSSet *speciesSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[animals valueForKey:@"species"]];
    return [[speciesSet] count] == 1;
}

BOOL sameSpeciesNumber(NSArray *animals, NSUInteger targetCount) {
    NSCountedSet *speciesCounts = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:[animals valueForKey:@"species"]];
    for (id species in speciesCounts) {
        if ([speciesCounts countForObject:species] == targetCount)
            return YES;
    }
    return NO.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a hash table (or dictionary in objective-C) with the key on the species, incrementing the count every time.

For clarity (pseudo-code):

```
// N is 4 for your particular case
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   hashtable[ object[i].species ]++;

hashtable[ Species.PIG ]; // number of pigs (constant)
```

or if you want to unroll it manually:

```
hashtable[ object1.species ]++;
hashtable[ object2.species ]++;
hashtable[ object3.species ]++;
hashtable[ object4.species ]++;
```

now you can check through the species to see the count:

```
for each key in hashtable
    if ( hashtable[ key ] == 3 ) // species "key" has 3 items
        /* Code */
```

of course, "hashtable" can be just a simple array if species is just a simple enum/integer.  The above should be the same theory in either case.

Comment: +1, For a small case like this one, even just a regular C array would suffice.

Comment: I agree, though you would have to make a mapping table (unless species is a simple enum/int) which might be more than halfway there anyhow.

Comment: Okay yes, so actually if I use 4 int values instead of animal names, so
    object1.species = 1;

then I can just use a C array and do something like this:

  int speciesArray[4] = {object1.species, object2.species, object3.species, object4.species };

and then just use some command like

    [how many of speciesArray elements are the int 0];

right? So I just need to figure out what is the correct function to use to count how many 0s there are in the speciesArray array?

Comment: I added some pseudo code to make it clearer.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense now, I get it! Thanks for all the help my pal!

Answer (score 1):

You can count how many comparisons match of all possible comparisons. If exactly 1 comparison is true, then exactly 2 items are the same, if 3 comparisons match, exactly 3 items are the same. This example is in C, you'll have to convert it to objective-C on your own.

```
int count = 0;
count += object1.species == object2.species;
count += object1.species == object3.species;
count += object1.species == object4.species;
count += object2.species == object2.species;
count += object2.species == object3.species;
count += object3.species == object4.species;
// count 0 - all different
// count 1 - exactly 2 are the same
// count 2 - two pairs of 2
// count 3 - exactly 3 are the same
// count 6 - all are the same
```

The counting can also be implemented as a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < 4; j++)
        count += objects[i].species == objects[j].species;
```

This approach only works if the amount of objects is 5 or less. Because of this and the fact that the amount of comparisons scales quadratically, it's better to use a hashtable if the amount of objects is larger.